# Sudden "unknown MySQL server host error" on AWS with Django

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I am receiving a lot of error reports from my Django server throwing:

`(2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'my-address.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (0)")`.

The server has been connecting to this database for more than a year without any issue. But this morning I suddenly started to receive this error, even though I didn't do any changes to the code.

Furthermore, when I connect to my website, it actually loads data from the database fine.

Apparently there is a random chance that it won't manage to connect?
Any idea what can cause that and how to fix it?

I am on Amazon lightsail.

Comment: This smells like a temporary DNS (hostname - to - IP address lookup) failure. When this happens again, immediately try `ping my-address.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com` from the host running your Django program, if you can. And from your own machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an active AWS DNS resolving incident in us-east-1 region. Seems like it will be mitigated soon.
https://status.aws.amazon.com/

[image]

UPDATE: The issue is now resolved as updated by AWS.

Comment: Looks like that was it. The issue disappeared :)